# Replace string that contains dynamically numbers

Tags: javascript

i have a variable that contains the string: attribute_value[XXX][] where XXX every time that page loads is a 3-digit number that changes every time.

How can i use .replace function in javascript to replace attribute_value[XXX][] with something specific regardless the XXX value?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `str.replace(/\d+/, 'something specific')`…?

Comment: `"attribute_value[123][]".replace(/\d+/, '456') ` =>  `"attribute_value[456][]"`

Comment: Yes but how to identify the attribute_value[XXX][]? I need the whole attribute_value[XXX][] to be replaced. So if for example attribute_value[216][] or attribute_value[5][] or attribute_value[13][] is loaded to be replaced with for example the text removed

Comment: That `/\d+/` matches only digits.  Read about regular expressions here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: `.replace(/attribute_value\[\d+\]\[\]/, "...")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression for that

```
str.replace(/attribute_value\d+/, 'aa');
```

here '\d' indicates digits and '+' indicates one or more occurances

```
str.replace(/attribute_value\d{3}/, 'aa');
```

Use this if you want to replace only first 3 digits

Comment: The string to replace is `attribute_value[XXX][]` not `attribute_valueXXX`

Comment: then just do this
attribute_value[xxx] = attribute_value[xxx].replace(/\d+/, 'something');